# Only numbers and only 3 charachteres with keypressed in JTextField Java

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have tried that my `Jtextfield` only accepts `3 numeric characters`, but it continues to  accept letters and symbols despite the restriction.

Is there another way to validate without using `DocumentFilter`?

**CODE:**

```
      private void txtnumerofacturaKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                            
      numerocifras = txtnumerofactura.getText().length();
         if (numerocifras < 3) {
           txtnumerofactura.setText(txtnumerofactura.getText() + 
           String.valueOf(evt.getKeyChar()));
         }
      }
```

> INPUT:2
>
> OUTPUT: 22

Comment: _Is there another way to validate without using DocumentFilter_ If you know that `DocumentFilter` is the correct approach, why do you continue with this hack solution?

Comment: Try [JFormattedTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) here is an howto: https://www.java-tutorial.org/jformattedtextfield.html